# Why do we have the [stackoverflow.com] tag if we're not supposed to use it?

Tags: discussion, tags

The wiki for the [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) tag on the main site says:

> ***DO NOT USE THIS TAG*** If you need to ask questions about the site itself, especially if you are looking for support or reporting a bug, you should do so on Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

If we're not supposed to use the tag then why hasn't it been burned? Is it supposed show new users that meta exists if they try to tag a non-meta question [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com)? I think this needs some explanation.

Comment: It's probably left over from the split from [meta.se], where the tag used to be relevant, but it's now unnecessary over at MSE too (there's a question over there about that fact).

Comment: @Cupcake He's talking about the tag on SO, not here on Meta.

Comment: @BilltheLizard oops...thanks for pointing that out. On a side note, I tried looking for that MSE question that talks about the `[stackoverflow]` tag there, but I think I might have just gotten it confused with [Can we burninate the \[stack-exchange\] tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237139/163250) instead.

Comment: As with so many bad tags, you shouldn't just strip them of all questions that they're on and move on with your day.  Questions using this tag are far more likely to have other problems, as such actual people should be going through the tag and handing all of the posts as is appropriate, moving them to meta, closing them, whatever is needed.  When all of the posts are handled appropriately, the tag will disappear on its own.

Comment: Close [Parse Title & Description from any website (Just like how Facebook Link Share works)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3847808/456814) as a recommendation question. Same with [Is there a questions-and-answers Rails plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1800097/456814).

Comment: [Authentication like Stack Overflow in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732836/authentication-like-stack-overflow-in-c-sharp) should be closed too, in my opinion.

Comment: This doesn't belong on [main], but here on Meta instead: [How to fix Stackoverflow login after chaging to gmail? login id's have changed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23871884/456814).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the questions tagged [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) were posted before the Meta site existed. The tag makes sense on some of those questions, and a few of them even look to be on-topic on Stack Overflow itself. Most of the recent uses of the tag can probably be removed.

Comment: Is really necessary to have a tag for developing something "similar" to Stack Overflow? I mean, who is the expert on Stack Overflow (Skeet doesn't count ;))