# Welcome to [stackoverflow.com]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

So, we have a [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) tag:

> ***DO NOT USE THIS TAG*** If you need to ask questions about the site itself, especially if you are looking for support or reporting a bug, you should do so on Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Someone asked "[Why do we have the [stackoverflow.com] tag if we're not supposed to use it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267130/why-do-we-have-the-stackoverflow-com-tag-if-were-not-supposed-to-use-it)," but that wasn't an official burninate request.

Apparently, it has some use:

> Some of the questions tagged stackoverflow.com were posted before the Meta site existed. The tag makes sense on some of those questions, and a few of them even look to be on-topic on Stack Overflow itself. Most of the recent uses of the tag can probably be removed.

But it mostly leads to off-topic questions like "How do I implement X like Stack Overflow?"

It has 61 questions; can we burn it?

Comment: I hope whoever burninated the more recent questions used [stackoverflow-api] for legitimate questions.  I looked over what's left and [stackoverflow.com] didn't seem relevant for any of them.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yes; it appears someone has taken the burnination into their own hands. I don't know where those 24 questions went, but none of the ones that remain strike me as particularly useful (i.e. the old ones I found when I first discovered this tag have now been retagged as something else).

Comment: [Maybe @animuson knows...](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2539819/revisions)

Comment: @Braiam I guess he saved the day.